# How to get the clicked element's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I want to retrieve the ID of the clicked element (on the 'onclick; event.

```
<script>


 function myFunction(element)
 {
     var $id = element.id;
     $($id).click(function() {           
                    $.get('ajaxTestSrvlt?test=1', function(responseText) {                      
                          $('#firstName').val(responseText);      with the response text.
                    });
                });
 };

</script>
```

This is the element this function was called upon. I would like to get the ID of this raw from the above script. This only works when I directly give the "clickableRow" as to id to the Script. The "ID" is to be changed dynamically

```
 <tr id="clickableRow" style="cursor: pointer;" class='clickable-row' data-href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" onclick="myFunction(this)">
```

Comment: You could use `$(this)`. That will bind to the element being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have a inline event handler

```
<tr id="clickableRow" style="cursor: pointer;" class='clickable-row' data-href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.clickable-row').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            id = this.id;

        $.get('ajaxTestSrvlt?test=1', function (responseText) {
            $('#firstName').val(responseText);
            //here `id` is the id of the clicked tr
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would produce the same behaviour as the provided code. In the provided code, the first click on the clickableRow would add an additional onclick listener to the clickableRow, and the _next_ click would do the _$.get_. Of course, that may not have been the intention in the question...

Comment: @SimeonJM you are right... but now since the OP has accepted it, my assumption seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function myFunction(ele)
{
    var id=$(ele).attr("id");
     $('#'+id).click(function() {           
        //code here
     }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
onclick="myFunction(this.id)
```

Instead of

```
onclick="myFunction(this)
```

Get your id on my function

```
function myFunction(getid) {
   alert(getid);
}
```